# Opening HTA file from another HTA file

Tags: file, hta

Alright, so I am creating a simple program that should, when you click the link open another .HTA file. For example:

```
Sub RunProgram 
    Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "explorer.exe", "Virus_Support.hta", , , NORMAL_WINDOW
 End Sub
```

Then later on...

```
<body> 
<button onclick="RunProgram">Run Program</button> <p>
</body>
```

However, it returns a 'Variable is undefined: objShell' error. I am trying to get virus_support.hta to open up from the SupportMain.hta file...not on IE or any browser.

Comment: Actually HTAs are run by mshta.exe. Try `mshta.exe` instead of `explorer.exe`. I think also a full path is needed for `Virus_Support.hta`. Btw, what are you actually doing, support for virus sounds suspicious =).

Comment: I see... : ). Did you get your code to work with `mshta.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub RunProgram
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
    objShell.run("Virus_Support.hta")
End Sub
```